# Make a position fixed not scrollable

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, client

I was wondering if there is a way to make a div with position fixed immobile, so if the user scrolls the div will be immobile to the initial position. I need it because I have a toast spawning inside another div, and I need this toast in foreground otherwise it will spawn inside the div (with scrollbar and partially visible).

That's an example image to explain better:

With position absolute:
[image]

With position fixed (the desired effect):
[image]

That's my component code (it's a child component):

```
        <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" style="position:absolute; z-index:999; left:80%; width:300px;opacity:1;cursor:unset !important" *ngIf="!isCollapsed && onlyOnePopup == dataItem.Id">
          <div class="toast-header" style="background-color: #00549F;">
            <strong class="mr-auto" style="color:#fff;"></strong>
            <button (click)="onlyOnePopup = null && isCollapsed = true" type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true" class="close" style="color:white;">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="toast-body" style="font-family:Font; white-space:pre-line; color:black; cursor:unset">
            TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `position: fixed`, and then set the exact position that you want. Here's a snippet showing you an example of how to do it.

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.fixed-div {
  width: 200px;
  heigth: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class="fixed-div">
     Fixed Div
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Programming is all about options. I showed two options, I'm pretty sure there's more

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `left: 80%` try `bottom: 0; right: 0` along with `position: fixed;` and then set `right-margin` accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunatly, it's still moving when I scroll

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce this issue in stackblitz by any chance? I will fix it then

Answer (score 2):

the main thing is to set the height of html as 100vh (veriable height) and width to 100vw(veriable width). this will set your page to 100% of the space available in the browser window regardless of size. then set the toast div to fixed with the right and bottom set where you like (0 for bottom and right puts it in the lower right corner completly)

you cannot set a fixed point with no reference to what it should be fixed to. so by setting the html page size explicitly, the fixed position can be set based off that.

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.toast {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 15rem;
}

.display-content {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="display-content">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur efficitur felis neque, et viverra tellus fermentum eget. Quisque nunc tellus, pulvinar id felis sed, sodales iaculis magna. Morbi sodales pellentesque sapien, nec dignissim augue. Integer odio enim, posuere et convallis et, ultricies in odio. Curabitur felis libero, iaculis et elit in, feugiat tempor augue. Duis finibus mattis leo eu facilisis. In faucibus tincidunt dui. Nullam pulvinar est vel mauris rhoncus euismod. Praesent vel pharetra neque, vitae sollicitudin enim. Nunc placerat sagittis malesuada. Suspendisse potenti. In tempus risus eget dapibus semper. Vestibulum vitae elit congue, tempor quam at, ultricies mauris.
</p>

<p>
Suspendisse ut ullamcorper libero. Quisque consectetur gravida nisi, non faucibus turpis iaculis nec. Phasellus vulputate, tellus sed dapibus dapibus, turpis mauris facilisis eros, eu sagittis quam ante eget felis. In nec nisl at lorem tincidunt vulputate vel eu est. Phasellus ipsum velit, placerat quis pulvinar non, auctor at ex. Nam pharetra dolor a semper feugiat. In sed commodo mauris. Aenean in turpis sed orci molestie efficitur quis id orci. Duis laoreet leo a nulla interdum hendrerit. Suspendisse molestie tristique semper. Vestibulum convallis purus et orci mollis sodales. Praesent ut lectus laoreet, suscipit velit nec, pharetra neque.
</p>

<p>
Morbi placerat metus a eros viverra, luctus ultricies eros fringilla. Nunc mollis lorem at lacus lobortis, vitae blandit ex condimentum. Maecenas et ultricies tortor, sit amet ornare risus. Nunc id nisl et ligula commodo vehicula in et risus. Pellentesque molestie et risus quis lacinia. Quisque quis risus laoreet, venenatis enim nec, hendrerit nisl. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque pretium turpis vestibulum urna auctor sodales. Vivamus mattis sem eu tellus scelerisque tempus. Sed venenatis felis in mollis suscipit. Sed quis felis ac erat facilisis pellentesque eget nec purus. Phasellus libero odio, semper sed auctor at, ultrices non nibh. Proin consectetur metus sed ultrices aliquam. Pellentesque placerat, nibh vitae semper sodales, mauris elit vestibulum mauris, sit amet condimentum odio est tincidunt neque. Quisque metus lacus, ullamcorper non accumsan nec, placerat et lectus.
</p>

    <p>
Vestibulum nec sem ex. Pellentesque volutpat quam eget justo rhoncus congue. Etiam in lorem pellentesque, pulvinar turpis non, dignissim nibh. Etiam eget urna congue, sodales nulla eget, fringilla lorem. Aliquam suscipit dapibus augue eget mollis. Phasellus feugiat sagittis massa, in posuere odio ultrices eu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi eleifend augue vel sagittis pellentesque. Cras auctor interdum purus non fermentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer elit mi, molestie vitae pulvinar vel, elementum et dui. Pellentesque leo risus, elementum eu accumsan nec, pharetra non massa. Phasellus pulvinar mollis aliquam.
    </p>
    
     <p>
     Sed elementum facilisis erat, in molestie tortor varius ut. Vestibulum dapibus dolor quis mi malesuada, id venenatis ante vulputate. Aliquam fermentum viverra ante, sit amet rhoncus turpis laoreet vel. Vestibulum a vestibulum dolor. Mauris ut efficitur nunc. Donec sit amet consectetur orci. Ut at erat non sem mattis dictum. Aliquam vestibulum nulla nunc, nec varius est vestibulum sit amet.
    </p>
    
         <p>
     Aenean imperdiet eros non eleifend molestie. Nullam venenatis nibh non pellentesque imperdiet. Quisque volutpat eros non odio convallis ultricies. Etiam convallis facilisis libero, a commodo tellus condimentum quis. Curabitur congue erat ut tincidunt eleifend. Donec tincidunt ullamcorper consequat. Etiam iaculis elementum fermentum.
    </p>
    
         <p>
     Fusce vehicula libero nisl. Aliquam tempor sem at lacinia facilisis. Donec vestibulum sit amet augue non rhoncus. Nulla sagittis leo elit, a interdum metus dapibus in. Nulla in mattis nunc. Sed sit amet est in tellus vehicula molestie vel tempor nisl. Donec dignissim est lectus, ac pharetra neque bibendum nec.
    </p>
    
         <p>
     Sed porta dui eget turpis scelerisque rutrum. Aliquam eu diam nec nunc ultrices hendrerit. Quisque convallis metus vitae tellus fermentum finibus. Cras id ullamcorper nisl. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed gravida lorem non blandit porta. Aliquam ac dui laoreet, interdum dui vel, pellentesque arcu. Aenean gravida nunc sit amet arcu rhoncus mollis. Nullam sit amet risus at urna dictum pharetra. Nunc maximus condimentum dui, sed hendrerit metus pretium et. Curabitur eu sollicitudin lorem, et luctus magna. Donec tincidunt id purus sed placerat. Proin vel tristique velit. Donec ornare nisi at laoreet luctus. Integer id metus molestie, fermentum massa non, porta diam.
    </p>
    
         <p>
     Quisque at volutpat augue. Maecenas porttitor ornare scelerisque. Ut pretium sapien a placerat dapibus. Fusce vel urna eu sem blandit euismod. In imperdiet eros sit amet quam tempor aliquam. Morbi volutpat tincidunt massa, non convallis dui pharetra nec. Ut velit odio, pellentesque mollis sodales et, eleifend ac libero. Curabitur orci ante, varius ac congue id, rutrum id leo. Pellentesque massa massa, lacinia pretium sapien ut, dignissim congue ipsum. Aliquam commodo leo in nisl pharetra, sed viverra est auctor.
    </p>
</div>



<div class="toast">This is a toast</div>
```